# Find those who play with Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, account-suspension

Recently I heard about a new bad activity in some software companies. Some of that companies programmers use Stack Overflow as a fun and game site and send wrong answers just for fun.

There must be a way to find and block this kind of activities and disable accounts of that users otherwise Stack Overflow will turn to a unusable site full of wrong answers.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

I found this under [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) > Restriction section:

Use of the Network or Services to violate the security of any computer network, crack passwords or security encryption codes, transfer or store illegal material including that are deemed threatening or obscene, or engage in any kind of illegal activity is expressly prohibited. Under no circumstances will Subscriber use the Network or the Service to (a) send unsolicited e-mails, bulk mail, spam or other materials to users of the Network or any other individual, (b) harass, threaten, stalk or abuse any person or party, including other users of the Network, (c) **create a false identity or to impersonate another person**, or (d) **knowingly post any false, inaccurate or incomplete material**.

Comment: Their answers willbe downvoted; as such they are no more damaging than people who are just not very good at programming. Additionally after enough downvoted answers they will get an answer ban

Comment: Can you find examples?

Comment: Or any references for "I heard about"?

Comment: So, any reference for *"I know that this is turned to a known new fun way in some countries like Australia"*?

Comment: Well, I upvoted since this can happen but without some example it's very hard to give any real answer.

Comment: As a programmer in Australia... I haven't heard about this. If people are doing this for fun, it sure isn't many people.

Comment: I think that there is no other way and we can just downvote wrong answers. Is there any policy for StackExchange sites users?

Comment: @S.Yavari you mean policy like "don't post wrong answers on purpose"? No, it's common sense.

Comment: This is just like spamming and there must be some sort of rule or policy for users of a site like this. This is a big site with so many users and a good rank in google search. Anyway, I realized that there is no rule or policy to protect users from this kind of activities. Thanks.

Comment: I found some useful rules in Terms of Service. Actualy there is some helpful rule. You can find it under Terms of Service>Restrictions.

Comment: @S.Yavari There is protection against it. Richard's answer states that protection. Wrong answers get downvoted, invalid answers get deleted. Users who provide a lot of poor answers eventually get answer-banned and can no longer post answers. If this game even exists (I _live_ in the country you named, and I have never heard of this being a thing _anyone_ does) it's going to be pretty short-lived as the people in question will no longer be able to post answers at all.

Comment: This behavior is not new. In fact, it's an everyday occurrence.

Comment: @BoltClock, do you mean bad behaviour *by companies*? If so: any more details about that? (Just curious, as I simply cannot understand why software companies would allow their personnel to do this, or even encourage it.)

Comment: Oops my bad, I didn't see the part about posting wrong content specifically. I don't know about that.

Comment: @Bolt so you just mean wrong answers get posted everyday? :)

Comment: Until some evidence is presented, this sounds pretty much as an Internet hoax... One of those that pitches country against country...

Comment: There is no way to determine whether incorrect content is posted accidentally or deliberately, is there. I agree this sounds like some sort of hoax

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is exactly why we vote on answers. Anyone who posts deliberately bad answers will inevitably have their answers downvoted; allowing correct answers to rise to the top and bad answers to float to the bottom. Someone answering wrongly because of malice is no different to someone posting wrongly out of a lack of knowledge- the system of voting deals with both.

Additionally someone who posts only wrong answers will have all of their answers down voted; after sufficient poorly received answers they will automatically receive an answer ban and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Enjoy your [second Reversal badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/reversal?userid=220332)! :-P

Comment: @Sha success! Although they're not quite as rare beasts on meta

Comment: True, but still... gold! :-)